# javascript validation of username and password

Tags: javascript, validation, alphanumeric

I am working on a homework assignment and have been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to do the following:

1. uName - 
   requires something to be entered (if not throws error), 
   requires alphanumeric with at least one letter and one character (if not throws error),
   otherwise passes checks and increments the checkev counter
2. password -
   requires something to be entered (if not throws an error), requires the character count to be greater than or equal to 8 characters (if not throws an error), otherwise passes checks and increments the checkev counter

At this point, I have the original errors that are triggered by no entry, however, once I test the second case of not meeting alphanumerics or 8 characters I do not get the expected response.

Below is an example of the JS I have written thus far as well as the HTML:

Any help would be largely appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```js
window.onload = init;
    function checkRegistration() {
        var checkev = 0;
        var uName = document.pageForm.userName.value;
        var alphaNum = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
        var password = document.pageForm.password.value;
        
       if (uName == "") {
            document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = "A username is required.";
            checkev=0;
        } else if (uName.match != alphaNum)
            document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = "Username must contain at least one letter and one number, no special characters.";
        {
            document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = "";
            checkev++;
        }
        
        
        if (password == "") {
            document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = "A password is required.";
            checkev = 0;
        } else if (password.lenth >= 8)
            document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = "A password of at least 8 characters is required.";
        else {
            document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = "";
            checkev++;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Invitation Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="js/registration.js"></script>
</head>
    <form name="pageForm">
        <form action="#">
            <label for="userName">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Enter your Username" />
            <span class="error" id="userName"></span><br><br>
            <label for="Password">Password:
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" />
            <span class="error" id="password"></span><br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkRegistration()">
            
            </form>
            </form>
```

Comment: `password.lenth >= 8` needs to be `password.lenth <= 8`

Answer (score 0):

1 typo and 1 logic issue.

Try `password.length < 8`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="Enter your Username" />

<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" />
```

you miss `id` attribute when you used `getElementById()`
and good luck...

Answer (score -1):

Do not hard code your validation simply use V4F

Check out https://v4f.js.org for more details

```js
import {Field, Schema} from "v4f";

export Schema({
  username: Field()
    .alpha()
    .min(1)
    .required(),
  password: Field()
    .min(8)
    .required()
});
```